# jQuery/JS signature PNG image encoded?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image

I am using this plugin: http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-to-image/

I've followed it properly and submit the JSON image code via AJAX and have it return `echo imagepng(sigJsonToImage($_POST['image']));`

I then `console.log` the `result` and it returns the below:

```
�PNG


IHDRSs3�\IDATx���y\T�����,���̰o�l"�"��⒙v��*mf��n��~�w�Y�歴4��5۬�7˭n���� ��#̰
�003s��1�ȫ��0�̜��/<���h�5��9�˱X,�Rm����7t��s_}��es�\΍��d;�CNo~�S$���p>��%��ڲ���]�MfjL�d����~��;:
�
0���Z�f�����Uy����<�����=��70�,Y���.�1�G�����h?�'��A���Cgxz��c�
B���ѯ=��*A�P0`(_��5k�;P�t���e��i3��=�w{�G6�خ5���~uv�̓��`�P����z�������/W��qI�DpGP�[�pњ/r-2;%t��#]�����wseye{Ύ�B�S��^|�M�R����D����n��W8��Ҵ'f��=��zJ�nkZ��O^���8�����z�@c���}��ճ�|�������Ŋ�w~�v�F�<���{e�ntOC����G����q��J��}�r�X�L�D0,P>BQ������.��hr���L����g4�Wl=��T%!dՃ)/�!���`x��|eyj��gk�<����=�I�D0�X]�W��8[�������Ԙ�a:����So��� <#��|�}_�#�D����/scC���D�z#!���e�N�ǥ{z|w�b�7g�<�g+gk�:tB�h$v�`
6��䥆[�X,d��)����z�.���*�����u�+�o��_�e2S�Lypr�p�Ng0Bܰ{;c��|J�n����ݽ��c�ڵzB�������`Q�4]=��Pute�
ڐ�f����FB�W;�-�3��K����+�����_�a���tz   !Bli��(EYVl=�s�!�G���sl���U]!��
�40+ʷ��s�OU�����{}�G��Ԛ�B��j`�/ߎ������;W��w��٭�v��j'c8x����V���C>x.#%���tv�B��s8���
*TOnʶX����{Ǉ�2���@qw����i�mZ}�Vߦѷk�m�|Ѯї7tX�-9J:&X�� ��
`:�-_u��G6���1={o�3����`$�]������[���6�+��ZC?��r��rՎ�B���+�%����c�O��?��@��p߄�5�'�8    ��^��5�\l�ί=TpE���w�]��%HD�H`��K�"�D�H x�_/�+Z������M�ʚ~ȭ����I/�O���L��B�C��`������G��^3��?'��uyC��ME�=i�FJ��P����ڜ�
��z�[,����+s��z�捻�>�[h�,c�%�/���0�����`|l�O'.6D�<��1��������������d�n�Nbe��y0��������`I�ؠ�q����\���#XXռb����>���0�C��h2/y����:/����2!6�|@)۾��[?nz=s�;q�lƸ��I�C�
�?`2�)EY�ܔ��L����w���p_�'"���
�������A�GQ�><�ͱ�g�7��I�    �{�_ٸ|�^ӹ2��bE�%ťڶ��C{=���]�����d�QҔ(?ۿR����o������y���1+%��q~c��Q����%�bCΥ��eM�&�z|X�gHaU��o���������-M��K��Zl�ʷ��s�|��ᐿ�0}^j�����+_�J�sQq���ԥƫ]=}�Gy����ce�1�|7�����/W��ʕg˔�˕M��=>1��M��Z+�-���$pxv_��{/����C6/����Qt�s��-�Z�ϹԐs��x�B���w��K�+�/O�����܃�����T�շ����#�w���{K�!Rq��X&q��Zpx�]�����׶���5��?w�X�ǹ�!)_}�vߙ�����kZ��u� �&�����&���<�dZZh�{/T6��+ϕ)*��o���>7D*��{F�=�d�Qr�0?1.����q��?U��{�,�ra�/L�{����������z���&GJ'���c���>|���p�d���u5JM�JS��T5uԪ�W�5}yi��qMf�����){}{�Oy5˷�X�����<'޴Ġ�¦'�������>�@��xy�A��\iі+��
��u�B]��a2BȨ�O?(�,_ni�ӛ���CS����x��lޭq���8D*�L��(���0*�SBe�-�.�W��
�Co0��M߼l������
�ˑ�S��Ǌy��9wѳ�);+�Ś�E��{L3�C>|>�^�g]���7P��$Ǌ�NW�|0 �t�Ku�չ���j���oV�a��j�Ц��:{ro��oo
�������ũ�ӥ�v�hd7�kl�e��N�ѕ��w�<�ȞU�F��uwuv�[4mf��/��;Vfb��g���j���{T]�!�]�{�e��;������+�O;Xmt���c�R�'޹z6�n}��F9XP�T�������m0���}%umR឵��<]��$1�wq��.�qޚ=���˧�������ك߳rar���F�A����{��e����?^i�z�\v�yn\(6���S�u����^�'$�-���H��'������ݿZ5ˮ��6��@�1�|�/Z�E��B&��>yini����_��蕇��7!���M1�|F�y��N�<ZFY2c̺%�
��R�{a�1����^¬̸ǧǈ��t��¬�Y�������L\�K�8`Lf����m��Η�!g���F?9+.D*�{4`
f��M�ww����k7���
��?^�w��LY8�9.�ٹ   w���{.���0�Z;?���WG~�v�B����ce�1�1x�k�|��t�ޝG�>?TZ���w0J�1!&`!���d�.ն��6��6�+k���~
`����?5bż���9�a�|�v7V��㾸 ���Ix��Q�j]�JS��V5uX�(�k��{ʶ/Ūn��M�ѼqW�{͔eL����S���Q]��Bes�eU~����C�c��/A��?P>��V5��z����?���
���˛/T6��+[��ՙ���$na��!Rq�T�'�s��5�n.\.ǶS��A�n���_���[O�O��3�CF��mj�5��Tꮦv]Ck�R����Y�Ԙ�T߷���L�����&E�&��:;��
��wV5/{�pu�UBȢ�ѯ�1o�����3U?��^�o����k�yܸP��ߔ(��H�����CK�|����]���/�Z,�K��ƒ��"�ʞX���tuQuK�A��P�)���}��<�RO�@o7����C����p{g˚^����A�� �}jR���������8��%͝6=)�U0�����P>�~�1�7��߲�B���8�z0��Yq��F�umo�#�_�k�?D���P>���P���1�F    a>�>3�=��67�:�с"3eA���P>���(���J_��t����r����ra�`���hv��n��s������!���$�tps(�`(պU��X��H\g�~t�h_!�sѠ����OO�;SM����J��J�P���ށs�����+-ZB�������S�Y�05EY>;X���3��o���Ջ�µM`>����{M�NW}y��s���#ro�G��r�%`i]�K�P�L��~���  a>t�/(�и�Pq���'ʯv��^^{'���i����f��6W�#(�Pr�% �d���[�Np(�0r�% �d��؂�.[�v�ɭ���e�����`;7.$��RB'�����tq�w�>:}���ջOV�*i4SBH��uٜ������uK@B�ǝ0�R�|J���7�M�삺NU̯3̈́��+[�9��P\����Ц�hίP-�?VT_R�����������)   �S���"�p�AQ����r+����v�Z����?5b��H�x��1��Z�v�(V-�?Q�h���9�=%!pZb`R������XӺ�d���*U]�#�"�E����\́�0EYJ�ڎ�-�ϻ�2�)�q7���1�i�����w��Z���S�̩�n7O�z�E.H����(s����J��C뚵C���F���1b��Q�L��`h�|��V�9VT��>�Bծ5��o%�v�;b�=c���
*��|v��,��;*���3N6C��]����vA��]P>`���vA��]P>`���vA��]P>`���vA��]P>`���vA��]P>`���vA��]P>`����>1�?!�~IEND�B`��PNG


IHDRSs3�\IDATx���y\T�����,���̰o�l"�"��⒙v��*mf��n��~�w�Y�歴4��5۬�7˭n���� ��#̰
�003s��1�ȫ��0�̜��/<���h�5��9�˱X,�Rm����7t��s_}��es�\΍��d;�CNo~�S$���p>��%��ڲ���]�MfjL�d����~��;:
�
0���Z�f�����Uy����<�����=��70�,Y���.�1�G�����h?�'��A���Cgxz��c�
B���ѯ=��*A�P0`(_��5k�;P�t���e��i3��=�w{�G6�خ5���~uv�̓��`�P����z�������/W��qI�DpGP�[�pњ/r-2;%t��#]�����wseye{Ύ�B�S��^|�M�R����D����n��W8��Ҵ'f��=��zJ�nkZ��O^���8�����z�@c���}��ճ�|�������Ŋ�w~�v�F�<���{e�ntOC����G����q��J��}�r�X�L�D0,P>BQ������.��hr���L����g4�Wl=��T%!dՃ)/�!���`x��|eyj��gk�<����=�I�D0�X]�W��8[�������Ԙ�a:����So��� <#��|�}_�#�D����/scC���D�z#!���e�N�ǥ{z|w�b�7g�<�g+gk�:tB�h$v�`
6��䥆[�X,d��)����z�.���*�����u�+�o��_�e2S�Lypr�p�Ng0Bܰ{;c��|J�n����ݽ��c�ڵzB�������`Q�4]=��Pute�
ڐ�f����FB�W;�-�3��K����+�����_�a���tz   !Bli��(EYVl=�s�!�G���sl���U]!��
�40+ʷ��s�OU�����{}�G��Ԛ�B��j`�/ߎ������;W��w��٭�v��j'c8x����V���C>x.#%���tv�B��s8���
*TOnʶX����{Ǉ�2���@qw����i�mZ}�Vߦѷk�m�|Ѯї7tX�-9J:&X�� ��
`:�-_u��G6���1={o�3����`$�]������[���6�+��ZC?��r��rՎ�B���+�%����c�O��?��@��p߄�5�'�8    ��^��5�\l�ί=TpE���w�]��%HD�H`��K�"�D�H x�_/�+Z������M�ʚ~ȭ����I/�O���L��B�C��`������G��^3��?'��uyC��ME�=i�FJ��P����ڜ�
��z�[,����+s��z�捻�>�[h�,c�%�/���0�����`|l�O'.6D�<��1��������������d�n�Nbe��y0��������`I�ؠ�q����\���#XXռb����>���0�C��h2/y����:/����2!6�|@)۾��[?nz=s�;q�lƸ��I�C�
�?`2�)EY�ܔ��L����w���p_�'"���
�������A�GQ�><�ͱ�g�7��I�    �{�_ٸ|�^ӹ2��bE�%ťڶ��C{=���]�����d�QҔ(?ۿR����o������y���1+%��q~c��Q����%�bCΥ��eM�&�z|X�gHaU��o���������-M��K��Zl�ʷ��s�|��ᐿ�0}^j�����+_�J�sQq���ԥƫ]=}�Gy����ce�1�|7�����/W��ʕg˔�˕M��=>1��M��Z+�-���$pxv_��{/����C6/����Qt�s��-�Z�ϹԐs��x�B���w��K�+�/O�����܃�����T�շ����#�w���{K�!Rq��X&q��Zpx�]�����׶���5��?w�X�ǹ�!)_}�vߙ�����kZ��u� �&�����&���<�dZZh�{/T6��+ϕ)*��o���>7D*��{F�=�d�Qr�0?1.����q��?U��{�,�ra�/L�{����������z���&GJ'���c���>|���p�d���u5JM�JS��T5uԪ�W�5}yi��qMf�����){}{�Oy5˷�X�����<'޴Ġ�¦'�������>�@��xy�A��\iі+��
��u�B]��a2BȨ�O?(�,_ni�ӛ���CS����x��lޭq���8D*�L��(���0*�SBe�-�.�W��
�Co0��M߼l������
�ˑ�S��Ǌy��9wѳ�);+�Ś�E��{L3�C>|>�^�g]���7P��$Ǌ�NW�|0 �t�Ku�չ���j���oV�a��j�Ц��:{ro��oo
�������ũ�ӥ�v�hd7�kl�e��N�ѕ��w�<�ȞU�F��uwuv�[4mf��/��;Vfb��g���j���{T]�!�]�{�e��;������+�O;Xmt���c�R�'޹z6�n}��F9XP�T�������m0���}%umR឵��<]��$1�wq��.�qޚ=���˧�������ك߳rar���F�A����{��e����?^i�z�\v�yn\(6���S�u����^�'$�-���H��'������ݿZ5ˮ��6��@�1�|�/Z�E��B&��>yini����_��蕇��7!���M1�|F�y��N�<ZFY2c̺%�
��R�{a�1����^¬̸ǧǈ��t��¬�Y�������L\�K�8`Lf����m��Η�!g���F?9+.D*�{4`
f��M�ww����k7���
��?^�w��LY8�9.�ٹ   w���{.���0�Z;?���WG~�v�B����ce�1�1x�k�|��t�ޝG�>?TZ���w0J�1!&`!���d�.ն��6��6�+k���~
`����?5bż���9�a�|�v7V��㾸 ���Ix��Q�j]�JS��V5uX�(�k��{ʶ/Ūn��M�ѼqW�{͔eL����S���Q]��Bes�eU~����C�c��/A��?P>��V5��z����?���
���˛/T6��+[��ՙ���$na��!Rq�T�'�s��5�n.\.ǶS��A�n���_���[O�O��3�CF��mj�5��Tꮦv]Ck�R����Y�Ԙ�T߷���L�����&E�&��:;��
��wV5/{�pu�UBȢ�ѯ�1o�����3U?��^�o����k�yܸP��ߔ(��H�����CK�|����]���/�Z,�K��ƒ��"�ʞX���tuQuK�A��P�)���}��<�RO�@o7����C����p{g˚^����A�� �}jR���������8��%͝6=)�U0�����P>�~�1�7��߲�B���8�z0��Yq��F�umo�#�_�k�?D���P>���P���1�F    a>�>3�=��67�:�с"3eA���P>���(���J_��t����r����ra�`���hv��n��s������!���$�tps(�`(պU��X��H\g�~t�h_!�sѠ����OO�;SM����J��J�P���ށs�����+-ZB�������S�Y�05EY>;X���3��o���Ջ�µM`>����{M�NW}y��s���#ro�G��r�%`i]�K�P�L��~���  a>t�/(�и�Pq���'ʯv��^^{'���i����f��6W�#(�Pr�% �d���[�Np(�0r�% �d��؂�.[�v�ɭ���e�����`;7.$��RB'�����tq�w�>:}���ջOV�*i4SBH��uٜ������uK@B�ǝ0�R�|J���7�M�삺NU̯3̈́��+[�9��P\����Ц�hίP-�?VT_R�����������)   �S���"�p�AQ����r+����v�Z����?5b��H�x��1��Z�v�(V-�?Q�h���9�=%!pZb`R������XӺ�d���*U]�#�"�E����\́�0EYJ�ڎ�-�ϻ�2�)�q7���1�i�����w��Z���S�̩�n7O�z�E.H����(s����J��C뚵C���F���1b��Q�L��`h�|��V�9VT��>�Bծ5��o%�v�;b�=c���
*��|v��,��;*���3N6C��]����vA��]P>`���vA��]P>`���vA��]P>`���vA��]P>`���vA��]P>`���vA��]P>`����>1�?!�~IEND�B`�1
```

How can I display this as an image in the browser?

Comment: Why not just use the URL as the "src" for an `<img>` tag?

Comment: give it to a new Blob instead of the console?

Comment: @Pointy: it's a POST...

Comment: @dandavis ah OK - well, we don't know that it *has* to be, but that would certainly pose a challenge.

Comment: what else do you expect? Unless you tell the browser you're outputting a PNG image, the browser'll default to assuming html. you need an `header('Content-type: /image/png')` in there.

Comment: @Pointy: well, he's using the post to upload an image worth of data, so i'd assume that pushes it out of the GET realm. having it work as GET would be super cool though... i think binary ajax or an iframe would work, depending on what needs to happen to/with the image. he might need saving/publishing  advice. kinda vauge.

Comment: I'd like to point out that `echo imagepng` is pointless, because `imagepng` will already output the image.

Comment: @dandavis oh oh oh NOW I see. Sorry.

Comment: @MarcB I'm already doing that...

Answer (score 2):

use base64_encode on the resulting string from imagepng like so
`base64_encode( imagepng( ... ) );`
now you can use that string as inline image
`<img src="data:image/png;base64,YOURBASE64STRINGHERE">`

```
$img = base64_encode( imagepng( ... ) );
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $img . '">';
```

alternatively you just return the `$img` and put it into an `img` tag on the client side.

Comment: along that line of thought, img.src=window.URL.createObjectURL(blobResponse) will allow much larger photos than a dataURL, usually with MUCH better performance.

Comment: `'<img src="data:image/png;charset=utf8;base64,' . base64_encode(imagepng(sigJsonToImage($_POST['image']))) . '">'.` still returns the same thing.